# how to fix int not subscriptable

Tags: python, matplotlib

i'm currently working with two arrays that contain coordinates respectively. I want to create a Rectangle with the values of these coordinates (this is only a snippet of the code but it's where the problem seems to be):

```py
for j in range(0, len(sub_x)):
        aux_x = sub_x[j]
        aux_y = sub_y[j]
        int_x = int(aux_x)
        int_y = int(aux_y)
        print("ints: ", int_x, int_y)
        rectangle = Rectangle(int_x, int_y,1,1)
        ax.add_patch(rectangle)
```

I'm getting "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" in the line with the declaration of the rectangle. I created all of the auxiliary variables to be extra sure that i wasn't subscripting the int. Can anyone tell what's going on?

Edit: Full traceback:
" File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 728, in **init**
self._x0 = xy[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"
Rectangle is imported from matplotlib like so:

```py
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
```

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback message?  Where is `Rectangle` defined?

Comment: fwiw a shorter way of getting those two ints would be to iterate over `for aux_x, aux_y in zip(sub_x, sub_y):`

Comment: [`Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) takes a tuple for `xy`, not 2 separate ints: `rectangle = Rectangle((int_x, int_y), 1, 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the matplotlib doc: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html

the `xy` parameter to `Rectangle` should be a tuple, not two different parameters; that's the thing that's being subscripted (inside the constructor).  This should work:

```
for xy in zip(sub_x, sub_y):
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle(xy, 1, 1))
```

Note that `zip`ping `sub_x` and `sub_y` together gives you `x, y` tuples in exactly the form that you need them for the `Rectangle` constructor.